# How do I save the information Google Chrome is saving about the links I click on?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, browser, hyperlink, save

Apologies in advance if SO isn't the best Stack Exchange group to post this question to; please migrate if you think it warrants it.

I use Google Chrome as my web browser. As a crossword constructor, I regularly use the website Onelook.com to search for words that may fit certain spots in my puzzle. An example page from Onelook is below.

[image: Example screenshot of onelook.com]

To mark words I have already considered, I click on them so that the link turns purple. Chrome seems to track which links I have clicked on in this way and saves this information somewhere such that if I search for some other pattern, words I've already clicked on in previous searches show up as purple in the new searches.

My question is, I think, simple: Where is Chrome storing this information? And, more importantly, how can I save this information so that if I ever have to switch computers or what have you, I can take this information about which words I've already considered with me?

Thanks in advance for the help!